# Using named routes vs. using url_for()

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When should one use named routes vs. using url_for with a {:controller => "somecontroller", :action => "someaction"} hash?

Is one preferred over the other and why?  Is one more maintainable or more efficient w.r.t. performance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It might help to understand what named routes are doing.

Defining a Named route creates a wrapper around url_for providing the options required for the created route. Routing resources creates many named routes.

With that in mind, the overhead of calling a named route as opposed to url_for with the options needed is negligible. So if you're linking to a specific resource, named routes are the way to go. They're  easier to read, type and maintain.

However, don't discount url_for. It has many creative uses thanks to the way it handles missing options. It is very useful when it comes to keeping views DRY that are used from multiple nested sources. Ie: when you have a blog_posts controller and posts_controller sharing the same views.

I strongly encourage you to read the [url_for documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#M001596). To help figure out where those places it makes sense to use url_for are.

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer named routes as it's shorter and does the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

named route is very neat.

```
 map.with_options :controller => "company", :action => "show", :panel => "name" do |m|
   m.company '/company/:action/:id/:panel'
 end
```

Then you can call

```
company_url :id => 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If you set up your routes and resources carefully, you shouldn't need any hash routes, only named ones (either built-in via `map.resource` or custom `map.<something>` ). Hash routes are useful, if you have to create links based on dynamic content. Something like:

```
link_to @post.title, :controller => (@user.is_admin ? 'admin/posts' : 'public/posts'), :action => 'show', :id => @post
```

(This is just a forced example, but you should get the gist of it :)